# Setting $0 in zsh’s source?

Tags: command-line, ssh, zsh

I’m trying to create a command that behaves like a “symlink through ssh”, i.e. calls a remote script as if it was called locally. My script is:

```
#!/bin/zsh
if (( "$#" = 0 )); then
    echo "Usage: $0 <number>" >&2; exit 1
fi
if ! [[ "$1" =~ '^[0-9]+$' ]]; then
    echo "error: “$1” is not a valid number" >&2; exit 1
fi
```

For this I’ll use `<(command)`, a process substitution that will create a fifo with a path like `/proc/self/fd/<n>`, redirect `command`’s stdout to it, and evaluate to that path. `fifo=<(echo 'hi!'); echo $fifo; cat $fifo` will echo `/proc/self/fd/14` (or so) and then `hi!`.

So this should do the trick, let’s see if the “Usage” thing works. I’ll save this script into my $PATH and execute it by its filename `exec-remote`.

```
#!/bin/zsh
source <(ssh myserver 'cat bin/mycommand')
```

Almost! This results in the remote script saying

```
Usage: /proc/self/fd/12 <number>
```

instead of

```
Usage: exec-remote <number>
```

… which means that while sourcing the remote script’s code, `$0` is set to the process substitution’s fifo path.

But zsh’s `source` command seems to accept only positional parameters (`$@`):

```
#!/bin/zsh
source <(ssh myserver 'cat bin/mycommand') $0
```

… will make my script say:

```
error: “/proc/self/fd/12” is not a valid number
```

So how can I make zsh execute my remote code while leaving `$0` alone when doing so?

Comment: First of all `ssh 'cat myserver:bin/mycommand'` looks strange. `ssh myserver 'cat bin/mycommand'` seems syntactically better. I don't understand what the purpose of passing `$0` is (in this command: `source <(ssh 'cat myserver:bin/mycommand') $0`). Can you explain what behavior you are expecting?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you can save `$0` in a local bar and use that in your error msg.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski whoops, you’re right, I edited that `ssh` bit wrong. In my real script it works of course. About passing `$0`: zsh seems to override `$0` while `source`ing a file, and you *can* pass arguments to `source` which will make it override `$@` too, but there seems to be no way to influence how `$0` gets overridden.

Comment: In my case your script returns `bad math expression`. I had debugged it before I answered. For the main issue this is irrelevant though.

Answer (score 0):

I think `source` only gets in a way. Save the following (locally) as `exec-from-myserver`:

```
#!/bin/sh
name=${0##/}
exec zsh -c "$(ssh myserver "cat 'bin/$name'")" "$0" "$@"
```

Make it executable, then symlink to it:

```
ln -s exec-from-myserver mycommand
ln -s exec-from-myserver foo-bar-baz
# etc.
```

(Note: the string `cat 'bin/whatever_name_you_chose'` will be *parsed* on the remote side. Names with literal `'` will break the code or make it misbehave; you can even perform code injection by naming symlinks in a certain way. Since it's you who chooses names, it's not really critical. Use regular names and it will be OK.)

Now if you call `mycommand`, the local script will `exec` to `zsh` interpreting the remote `bin/mycommand` and `$0` in its context will be set to the useful value of previous (local) `$0`. Calling `foo-bar-baz` will try to pull and interpret the remote `bin/foo-bar-baz`. Examples:

```
$ ./mycommand
Usage: ./mycommand <number>
$ # This was your remote script talking.

$ ./mycommand 1
$ # Executed without complaint.

$ ././mycommand
Usage: ././mycommand <number>
$ # As you can see the remote script is aware of its local name and path used.

$ ./foo-bar-baz 
cat: bin/foo-bar-baz: No such file or directory
$ # This was the remote cat talking, only because there is no remote foo-bar-baz.
```

Notes:

- A nuance in my terminology: "the remote script" exists on the remote side as a file, but it is interpreted locally; "the remote cat" is truly remote.
- `exec-from-myserver` always uses `zsh -c`, the shebang in the remote script is completely ignored (your experiment with `source` ignored it as well).

Comment: Leave me a comment if shebang being ignored is an issue.